# d3,js setting X and Y domains on Horizontal Bar Chart with all negative values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How would the x and y domains be set for a horizontal d3 bar chart with *all negative values*? For a bar chart with all *positive values* the domains would be:

```
x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
       return Math.abs(d.value);
    })]);
  y.domain(data.map(function (d) {
        return d.dataset;
    }));
```

For a bar chart with *positive and negative values*, the domains would be:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.value;
}));

y.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    return d.dataset;
}));
```

But I haven't been able to get it right when a bar chart has *all negative values*.

Thank You for your consideration.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong when the values are all negative? `d3.extent` should work on negative values, all it does is look for the min/max.

Comment: The x axis starts at -10 instead of zero, the y axis line no longer displays, and the labels along the y axis are no longer displayed.

Comment: I had the following line of code: var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, 500]); When I replaced 500 with 400, the y axis and the labels appeared again. But the x axis still begins at -10. There is a gap between the x axis and the bottom of the y axis where the 0 - 10 line should be.

Comment: hard to say exactly what the problem is. If you could create a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem, that'd be helpful

Comment: If you set the values in the data array to all negative or all positive, it doesn't scale right. If you put mixed positive and negative values in the data array it looks great. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kavitha_2817/fmr1x1gu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing the margins improperly, as well as some other things.

https://jsfiddle.net/fmr1x1gu/7/

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
        return "bar bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive");
    })
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return width - x(d.value);
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(d.dataset);
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return x(d.value);
    })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth());
```

Comment: Thank You for looking into this Eric. I don't think your solution is quite what I'm looking for. The bars should start at zero on the x axis and the labels on the bars should be visible. Take a look at this fiddle where there are a mix of positive and negative values. https://jsfiddle.net/Kavitha_2817/fmr1x1gu/

Comment: Okay, i get what you're trying to do now. https://jsfiddle.net/fmr1x1gu/11/